# Line Break in Google script

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script

I am trying to use a line break in my code. However, the result doesn't seem to come in an expected way.

```js
function workday(){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
 to: "saketh.vuppula@gmail.com",
 subject: "Workday Checkin",
 htmlBody: "Hi Team,"+ "\n" + "To change your checkin on Workday, please use this link"
});
}
```

Comment: Use `<br/>` for HTML body

Comment: ‘\n’ is white space in html